# Como deixar sempre 20px de margem no fundo da página?

Tags: jquery, css

Eu tenho o CSS no `body`:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

Mas sempre buga, por exemplo, se eu usar `position: absolute;` ele perde essa margem de `20px`. Como fazer isso de outras maneiras?

Comment: Poderia definir "buga"? O que acontece mais exatamente?

Comment: se eu usar position: absolute; ele perde essa margem de 20px...

Comment: Sugiro compreender melhor como funciona o `position: absolute;`. Se tem algo absoluto dentro, para o CSS do body é como se não houvesse. É assim que funciona. Você precisa entender isso pra saber como lidar no seu caso específico.

Comment: É possivel criar um jsFiddle que reproduz o seu problema? se não vamos estar a adivinhar qual o seu problema possa ser...

Answer (score 3):

Se o problema for com position `absolute`, use um `bottom: 20px`. No mais esse `margin-bottom` na body resolve.

Comment: exemplo ???????????

Comment: @user3230262 Acho que isso é simples demais para requerer um exemplo. Tenha fé e use a solução do dsantoro ;)

Comment: body {
bottom 20px;
}

Comment: isso não funciona...

Answer (score 2):

Para valores absolutos, use a propriedade `bottom` apenas.

Use:

```
.divTeste { position:absolute; bottom:20px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="divTeste"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica por inspecionar elementos, se seu body esta 100% no height da pagina, se estiver o margin-botom:20px é para funcionar ou também position:absolute; bottom:20px;

Agora se no inspecionar elementos do seu body não estiver 100% é por que tem algo errado ai na sua página.